# Formulate as a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

> [image]

I tried to formulate linear program by using the split method.

> [image]

I used two equations to show the linear program, but it seems not right. Can anyone give me some ideas how to solve this one? Thanks

Comment:  is a scalar

Comment: Are $u$ and $v$ scalars or vectors? Can you rewrite $g$ using the $1$-norm?